# How do I install mysql-python for python2.7

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, centos

How do I install mysql-python for python2.7. The following script seems to use -I/usr/include/mysql which is empty, but I do have other folders like /usr/include/mysql51 and /usr/include/mysql55 which seem to contain header files.

```
sudo pip install MYSQL-python --allow-all-external
```

I got the following error:

```
Collecting MYSQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Installing collected packages: MYSQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MYSQL-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=pentium4 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=pentium4 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX
    _mysql.c:44:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
     #include "my_config.h"
                           ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-vXN9gu/MYSQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dKaHt3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

    running build

    running build_py

    creating build

    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7

    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7

    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb

    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb

    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb

    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb

    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb

    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb

    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb

    creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/MySQLdb/constants

    running build_ext

    building '_mysql' extension

    creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=pentium4 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=pentium4 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/_mysql.o -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX

    _mysql.c:44:23: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory

     #include "my_config.h"

                           ^

    compilation terminated.

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-vXN9gu/MYSQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dKaHt3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vXN9gu/MYSQL-python
```

Comment: Have you installed mysql first ? mysql-python needs python-dev (might be python-devel on centos/redhat) and libmysqlclient-dev (plus gcc etc and mysql-server if you are running the server on the same pc) . What mysql version ?

Comment: @Ixx Thanks! We already installed all the above you mentioned.

Comment: Which mysql version ? and have you installed all the developer tools and libraries? sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

Answer (score 2):

Why you wanted to face all those problems yourself? This was already resolved by package maintainers. Do:

```
yum install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing devel package
`sudo yum install mysql-devel`

Then install mysql-python using pip or yum:
`pip install mysql-python`  *OR*  `sudo yum install MySQL-python`